# What Star Trek episode is the "Kirk and Bones" nodding gif from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, episode-identification

[image: James Kirk and Leonard McCoy from Star Trek: The Original Series nodding]

What episode is the "Kirk and Bones nodding" gif from?

My guess is Season 1 from the apparent age and hair style of Shatner (Captain Kirk), but I couldn't find the scene in a cursory search of the episodes.

Comment: I've seen this same GIF with an orange ball bouncing back and forth.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is [*The Immunity Syndrome*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YsE5NgqW_s), season 2, episode 18.

Comment: yup - that's it. I was thinking it was an episode ending, go to credits type tag so I was just looking at green tunic episodes and checking the start and end of the episode